# Azure webapp AppInsights Profiler exceptions

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, appinsights

Have been noticing these task canceled exceptions in azure profiler logs for one of our apps only recently. Any pointers are appreciated. We do have other apps in the same resource plan but only this app seems to be having this issue

api/profileragent/v4/etlupload/start?iKey=yourikey1&stampId=southcentralus&machineName=yourmachinename&etlStartTime=2020-09-12T15:24:16.2764317Z A task was canceled.

Comment: This isn't much to go on. Resource group doesn't have any bearing on app performance, but if this app was sharing an app service plan with your other apps, that's a different story. I would suggest start with some [diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-diagnostics) on your web app to gather more insights on the exception being thrown. Feel free to post here.

Comment: @RyanHill-MSFT - This app is sharing the app service plan with 5 other apps. would that have any sort of impact on performance? what is the best practice in terms of having number of apps per app service plan?

Comment: Impact on performance is really based off the demands of your apps. Start with gathering diagnostics to determine where the task canceled exception is being thrown. Feel free to post the logs.